# reset an AG database to an earlier time without backup and restore

Tags: sql-server, availability-groups, snapshot

my dev team has been using DB snapshots to quickly revert a standalone 4TB db to an earlier state after they run a bunch of tests.  They now need the same process to reset that database to an earlier state, but it is now in an availability group.  I'm not aware of any way snapshots can be used in this regard.  traditional backup and restore method takes 6+ hrs and is not really an option to do multiple tests quickly.

I have not found anything on google that suggests there is a quick and fast way to reset a DB in an availability group back to an earlier state.  I don't have much experience with snapshots in general, let alone how they can work in an AG.

we are running SQL 2019 RTM.

Is there a way that db snapshots can be used in this situation to avoid the normal restore time?

Tried to directly restore the snapshot without taking the DB out of the AG, but I get this error:

```
RESTORE cannot operate on database 'agseed' because it is configured for database mirroring or has joined an availability group. If you intend to restore the database, use ALTER DATABASE to remove mirroring or to remove the database from its availability group.
```

then took the DB out of the AG, and was able to restore the snapshot to the primary, but there is no way to restore it "with no recovery" to seed the secondary.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is there a way that db snapshots can be used in this situation to avoid the normal restore time?

There isn't anything you can do with snapshots. One of the reasons (but not the only one) is that it rebuilds the log. Availability Groups (AGs) use the log. I would expect the same issues for any other features that use the log, such as Change Data Capture, Change Tracking, and replication.

From the [Revert a Database to a Database Snapshot](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/databases/revert-a-database-to-a-database-snapshot) documentation:

> The revert operation also overwrites the old log file and rebuilds the log.

---

> [...] took the DB out of the AG, and was able to restore the snapshot to the primary, but there is no way to restore it "with no recovery" to seed the secondary.

You can take a new full backup and use that, or use automatic seeding, but there is no supported way to make a secondary go back to some random point in time that it doesn't have. There is an AG mechanism called 'undo of redo', but that is log based and as I quoted above, this won't work because the log chain is broken.